using maui filesaver without file picker
I am using Maui which i'm really enjoying, but i'm now struggling. I'm trying to save a file using the community filesaver function. The following code works:
using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Text File"));
var path = await fileSaver.SaveAsync("subscribe.txt", stream, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

While this works it displays the file picker every time. What I would like to do is programatically save the file, without prompting the user, is this possible? I don't really mind where I save it to. I'm intending to download a file temporarily and save it, so that it can be loaded in the default app for that file type.
Thanks
Andrew

yes, just use the any standard C# class for writing files, like File.WriteAllBytes()

You can just use the C# IO to do that. In addition, you can also use the Java.IO in the maui android part.
